# Particle starting from rest

Tags: classical-mechanics

A particle starting from rest so that its velocity varies as the nth power of the distance described from the commencement of the motion. Prove that $\mathbb{n <= 0.5}$.

I know we need to express $\mathbb{v = k(x-a)^n}$ and need to prove that a particle starting from rest cannot have acceleration directly proportional to distance covered. I am unable to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Hint You can define the starting point as zero, getting rid of the $a$.  Now you have $\frac {dx}{dt}=kx^n$.  What happens if $n=1$ and you integrate this?  I don't see why there is a problem on $(0.5,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Place origin at the starting point. We are to assume that the velocity $dx/dt=v(t)=kx^n$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$ for some constant $k$.
It follows
$$
\frac{dx}{x^n}=k\,dt.
$$
Integrating gives $kt+C=\frac{1}{1-n}x^{1-n}$, so the initial condition $t=0, x=0$ implies $C=0$, $n<1$. Thus
$$
x=((1-n)kt)^{1/(1-n)}.
$$
Differentiating twice gives $a(t)=K t^{1/(1-n)-2}$ (I absorbed a number of things to another constant $K$). Infinite accelerations are physically impossible, but what happens if $t\to0$ from above and $n>1/2$.

Comment: Can we think of it like this: let $\mathbb{v=kx^n}$ then a=vdv/dx=knx^(2n-1), so if 2n-1>0; both v and a will become zero at time t=0, hence the particle remains at rest.